# Passing a property aquired asynchronously

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have this code:

```
export default class FinancesPage extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {users: []};
    }
    componentWillMount() {
    firebase.database().ref('Users').orderByChild('transactions').startAt(1).on('value', snap => {
            const users = arrayFromObject(snap.val());
            this.setState({users: users});
        });
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <NumberOfPurchasesComponent users={this.state.users}/>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

And this code:

```
export default class NumberOfPurchasesComponent extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {users: this.props.users};
    }
    componentWillMount() {

        const users = this.state.users;

        // Do stuff here    
    }
    render() {
        return (
            {/*And render stuff here*/}
        );
    }
}
```

What's happening right now: The parent element `FinancesPage` passes an empty array of `users` to the child `NumberOfPurchasesComponent`. I need it to pass a new value of the array every time there is an update.

And i want to pass the `users` from `FinancesPage` to `NumberOfPurchasesComponent`, but users data is obtained async. How can I make the `NumberOfPurchasesComponent` refresh when the variable value is obtained?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried to use `componentWillReceiveProps`? I mean something like:

```
export default class NumberOfPurchasesComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state={users: []}
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if(nextProps.users && nextProps.users!==this.state.users){
      this.setState({
        users: nextProps.users
      })
    }
  }

  render() {
      return (
          {/*And render stuff here*/}
      );
  }
}
```

This way the component knows when it has to re-render.

Comment: Why do I need to check if `nextProps.users!==this.state.users`?

Comment: It's the common procedure, 'cause you don't need to modify your state if props didn't changed. By the way, here I post a working solution that uses un unsafe method: `componentWillReceiveProps`. Offical documentation now suggest the use of `getDerivedStateFromProps`, that works pretty the same way, so you can consider to swipe that direction. Here is the [link](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#static-getderivedstatefromprops)

Answer (score 0):

The `FinancesPage` implementation looks good. The problem lies in `NumberOfPurchasesComponent` in this particular piece of code :

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {users: this.props.users};
}
```

Am assuming in the `render` method of `NumberOfPurchasesComponent` you are using `this.state.users` instead of `this.props.users`.

`constructor` runs only once. Now as you mentioned data is fetched async, which means `NumberOfPurchasesComponent` is initially rendered even before the the response is obtained. Hence its `constructor` method which runs only once sets the `users` state to `[]`. Even if the props gets updated from `FinancesPage`, as the render in `NumberOfPurchasesComponent` uses state, no re-render happens.

Try using `this.props.users` directly in `NumberOfPurchasesComponent` render and see if it works.

Comment: I need to do some math and sorting on the `users` property. So I think I need to do it in `componentWillMount` or on another event of this sort. Or am I missing something here?

Comment: I am guessing this math is done to transform users in the way render requires. In that case, invoke the transformation within render itself and pass `this.props.users` to the transform function.
This will ensure that always fresh data from the parent is used for all renders and transformations.

Answer (score 0):

As per **FinancesPage** page it is well and good with codebase, but problem is why you are making *setstate* if there is no any manipulation of user's data as you got from API call.

So without making setState just pass it as direct

```
 render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <NumberOfPurchasesComponent users={this.props.users}/>
            </div>
        )
    }
```

so whenever the API calls to fetch the response, here update value get in passed to *NumberOfPurchasesComponent* class.